# JDBC feeder for Elasticsearch

Tags: sql-server, bash, jdbc, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

I am trying to create a JBDC feeder to load data from SQL Server into elasticsearch. I am using the guide here: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc (search for heading 'How to run a standalone JDBC feeder').

I have successfully downloaded and installed elasticsearch and have it up and running. I have downloaded the JDBC driver for SQL server and moved it into the ./plugins/jdbc folder.

I am up to the part that involves creating a bash script. Before today, I have never even looked at a bash script and I'm having trouble getting it to work since I don't yet know half the syntax.

The elasticsearch directory is c:\elasticsearch-1.4.0

and here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

# ES_HOME required to detect elasticsearch jars
export ES_HOME= C:\elasticsearch-1.4.0

echo '
{
    "elasticsearch" : {
         "cluster" : "elasticsearch",
         "host" : "localhost",
         "port" : 9200
    },
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=MyDatabase",
        "user" : "MyUser",
        "password" : "MyPassword",
        "sql" :  "select * From MyTable",
        "treat_binary_as_string" : true,
        "index" : "MyFirstESIndex"
      }
}
' | java \
    -cp "${DIR}/*" \
    org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.feeder.Runner \
    org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.feeder.JDBCFeeder
```

What do I need to update in this script? Is it something in this line of the script:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

The reason I am doing this is because I'm looking for the best method to insert potentially tens of millions of records into elasticsearch from sql server in one go i.e a bulk insert.

Our first iteration of this involved getting each row of data in a table, converting it to a JSON document, and inserting into ES. This took about 10hrs to get all the data in there.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

Do this, if it's important for you to be in that working directory:

```
DIR="$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"
cd $DIR
```

Also, if it's not a typo, remove the space after `ES_HOME=`, and, when in doubt, use quotes:

```
export ES_HOME="C:\elasticsearch-1.4.0"
```

Additionally, with the Java `-cp` argument, if you want to include all the jar files (which I'm assuming), don't use quotes so the globbing works:

```
# Since you are already in the directory, you don't need DIR
JARS=$(echo ./*jar)
...
# On the cp line, substitute spaces with : to build the classpath
-cp "${JARS// /:}" \
```

I hope this helps. If you can give more details about how the script is failing, I could help more. Are you getting particular error messages?